# Phantom Bar showing up at bottom of screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I've got an iOS7 iPad app. I use storyboards. My root view controller is a tab bar controller. One of my tabs is a split view controller to view reports, which has a table view controller (embedded in a navigationController) in the left-hand split and view controller in the detail side.

I'm finding that I have a random bar across the bottom of both controllers. In the screen shot you can see it at the bottom of the left-hand pane. If I were to select a report which loads the detail side, you'd see the same thing there as well. No matter what I do I can't get it to go away... gotta be missing something simple. Any tips?

[image: phantom bar]

Here's the storyboard view. Note that there's some sort of a bar showing up in the Split view controller, but it's not there in the nav controller. I don't know if this bar is related to the problem or not. I suspect it's being inferred from the tabbarcontroller's bottom bar.

[image: Storyboard view]

Comment: Have you double checked the constraints for your table view?

Comment: @Mikael The bar isn't visible in the storyboard's NavigationController, and the view extends to fill it completely in all cases. I should point out that I do see "a bar" in the split view controller, but not sure if that's doing this or not.

Comment: Hmm I still think that this is a constraint issue. It looks more like your tableview isn't attached to the bottom and it is the background that looks like a bar.

Comment: @Mikael If that's the case, I see no way to fix it. I can't adjust the size of the table view (there are no anchors to drag). The same goes for the view in the detail view; from all appearances, they fill the entire view port.

Comment: Right click and drag downwards on your table view. Release while still on the view and a menu should pop up. Choose "Bottom space [...]".